# R: Conversion of Factor to Numeric on multiple rows using as.numeric(as.character(

Tags: r, character, numeric, r-factor

`as.character` works for a single element But it return the levels for multiple elements

```
> ImpDat <- read.table("C:/Users/Jeremy/Desktop/ElectronicsFinal/data_originalFull_Modified.csv",
                       header=TRUE, sep=",", na.strings="NA", 
                       dec=".", strip.white=TRUE)

> as.character(ImpDat[2,3:3])
[1] "40000000"
> as.character(ImpDat[2,2:3])
[1] "2" "8"
```

I guess I could use `lapply` and convert the whole dataset to type numeric... But just wondering if there is a way to take certain elements in a row and convert all of them simultaneously to type numeric.

Comment: Maybe try stringsAsFactors=FALSE in the call to read.table. That should solve your problem.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that you're selecting across columns (NOT rows) in the second example. That returns a data.frame rather than a factor. And as.character works differently on factors and data.frames. The easiest fix is probably.

```
as.character(as.matrix(ImpDat[2,2:3])
```

The `as.character()` is really just there to convert the matrix to a vector. If a matrix will work for you, you may not need that call.